# SQL Window Function - Number of Rows since last Max

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I am trying to create a SQL query that will pull the number of rows since the last maximum value within a windows function over the last 5 rows. In the example below it would return 2 for row 8. The max value is 12 which is 2 rows from row 8.

For row 6 it would return 5 because the max value of 7 is 5 rows away.

```
|ID  | Date       | Amount  
| 1  | 1/1/2019   |  7  
| 2  | 1/2/2019   |  3  
| 3  | 1/3/2019   |  4  
| 4  | 1/4/2019   |  1  
| 5  | 1/5/2019   |  1  
| 6  | 1/6/2019   |  12  
| 7  | 1/7/2019   |  2  
| 8  | 1/8/2019   |  4
```

I tried the following:

```
SELECT ID, date, MAX(amount) 
OVER (ORDER BY date ASC ROWS 5 PRECEDING) mymax
FROM tbl
```

This gets me to the max values but I am unable to efficiently determine how many rows away it is. I was able to get close using multiple variables within the SELECT but this did not seem efficient or scalable.

Comment: Show expected output in tabular format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the cumulative maximum and then use `row_number()` on that.

So:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by running_max order by date) as rows_since_last_max
from (select t.*, 
             max(amount) over (order by date rows between 5 preceding and current row) as running_max
      from tbl t
     ) t;
```

I think this works for your sample data.  It might not work if you have duplicates.

In that case, you can use date arithmetic:

```
select t.*,
       datediff(day,
                max(date) over (partition by running_max order by date),
                date
               ) as days_since_most_recent_max5
from (select t.*, 
             max(amount) over (order by date rows between 5 preceding and current row) as running_max
      from tbl t
     ) t;
```

EDIT:

Here is an example using row number:

```
select t.*,
       (seqnum - max(case when amount = running_amount then seqnum end) over (partition by running_max order by date)) as rows_since_most_recent_max5
from (select t.*, 
             max(amount) over (order by date rows between 5 preceding and current row) as running_max,
             row_number() over (order by date) as seqnum
      from tbl t
     ) t;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I am still running into an issue. My "amounts" do have duplicate numbers which is causing issues. I then attempted the second example you provided, however there are gaps in the dates of my source data. This then yields inaccurate results. I really need the number of rows to the most recent max and not datediff. Any additional help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @JDG . . . You explicitly state that you want the previous five rows, so gaps in the date should not matter.  If they are an issue, I would suggest that you ask a *new* question with appropriate sample data, desired results, and an explanation.

Comment: Hi Gordon. That is correct, it should be the max from the previous 5 rows. The datediff funtion is counting the difference between dates and not the difference in rows. For example the dates could be in the sequence 10/1/2019, 10/2/2019, 10/5/2019, 10/10/2019. The datedff would provide a "days_since_most_recent_max5" that does not match the difference in rows.

Comment: @JDG . . . In that case, you can use `id` rather than `date` -- if your ids are gapless and always increment by 1.

Comment: Yes, so thats what I originally tried in your first example. The issue is that there are duplicate "running_max" in the first part of the query. When the second part of the query looks for the row_number, it is selecting the incorrect record. In many cases the rows_since_last_max is returning values over 5. This is because its finding a duplicate running_max before the correct instance.

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff Please don't leave me hangin :)

Comment: @ Gordon Unfortunately this is not working as *rows_since_most_recent_max5* is always yielding zero.

Comment: @JDG . . . There should have been some conditionality there.  I revised the edited answer.

Comment: That worked, thanks! Just needed to add a closing parenthesis after `running_amount then seqnum end)` and change *running_amount* to *running_max*

Answer (score 0):

It would be :

```
select *,ID- 
(
SELECT ID
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      ID,amount,
      Maxamount =q.mymax
    FROM
      Table_4 
  ) AS derived
WHERE
  amount = Maxamount
) as result
from (

    SELECT ID, date,
    MAX(amount) 
    OVER (ORDER BY date ASC ROWS 5 PRECEDING) mymax
    FROM Table_4 
)as q
```